# Create a UINavigationController For present 2 UIViewController in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have 2 `UIViewController`s and want to have UINavigationController with UINavigationBar & UINavigationItem on them. But my code doesn't working ..

here is my code :

```
#import "testView1.h"
#import "testView2.h"

@interface testView1 ()

@end

@implementation testView1

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    testView2 *detail = [testView2 new];
    [navController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Actually what you are doing here is that you are just alloc and init a navigation controller with a rootview controller which is already present in the window. this step should be dont in AppDelegate, for proper result

Comment: @Subramanian no I just create UIViewController in storyboard and set it's class to testView1

Comment: @K.R.SaravanaKumar yea thanks. But how to do ?

Comment: @SaMiGiMiX are you using Storyboard ?

Comment: @K.R.SaravanaKumar no I just create UIViewController in storyboard and set it's class to testView1

Comment: thanks for your help, it works @K.R.SaravanaKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to embed navigation controller in storyboard as below :

First select your `testView1` in storyboard .

**Select Navigation Controller**

[image]

**And Changes as below**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   /// testView2 *detail = [testView2 new];
    testView2 *detail =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testView2 Identifier"]; // if you have add controller in storyboard
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @SaMiGiMiX Welcome and its my pleasure to helping you.

Comment: tnx. But I can't add navigationBar to navigation controller

Comment: you dont need  to add manually  . Navigation controller automatically add navigation bar for you .

Answer (score 0):

You won't see the first View Controller because you already push the second view controller upon the navigation controller.

Comment: no , my first ViewController Color is darkGray and after run my screen is darkGray ..